# <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden> error in using geopy on pythonanywhere servers

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, geopy

I am trying to get address from user location coords using geopy through my website which is hosted on pythonanywhere servers.
Following is the code I used in flask to get this done.

```
   from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
   geolocator = Nominatim()
   @app.route('/location', methods = ['POST'])
   def location():
       latitude = request.json['latitude']
       longitude = request.json['longitude']
       location = geolocator.reverse(str(latitude)+ "," + str(longitude))
       send_email("myemail@example.com","Location:",str(location.address))
```

Comment: do you know what is the error in geopy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [open url from pythonanywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597390/open-url-from-pythonanywhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here: free accounts on PythonAnywhere only have access to a limited set of external websites (the whitelist), to stop people from signing up for throwaway free accounts on our site and then using them to attack other sites.    My guess is that your GeoIP lookup is trying to access a non-whitelisted site.

We're generally happy to add sites to the whitelist if they have an official public API, so if you can track down what site your app is trying to access and give us the hostname and a link to the API docs, we can probably get it on there and your code will work.

(Or, of course, you can upgrade to a paid account -- because we can connect them to real people, they're not limited by the whitelist. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say from your question but maybe the problem is a decode error.

try this:

```
location = geolocator.reverse(str(latitude)+ "," + str(longitude), language="en")
```

that will make sure that the result will be in english, and not is some foreign language.

Comment: This did not solve this error.The error is regarding the urlib package i guess @omri_saadon